# JQuery cascading classes - exclude one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code to attach change code to a JQuery slider. I have two sliders in my application, one that increments by 1 and one that increments by 0.01

```
$(document).on('click tap', '.fund-changer .minus', function() {
    var sliderCurrentValue = $(this).next().slider("option", "value");
    $(this).next().slider("value", sliderCurrentValue - 1);
    return false;
});


$(document).on('click tap', '.fund-changer .minus .twodecplace', function () {
    var sliderCurrentValue = $(this).next().slider("option", "value");
    $(this).next().slider("value", sliderCurrentValue - 0.01);
    return false;
});
```

The slider to increment by 0.01 is the same as the other slider but with an additional `.twodecplace` class

How can I amend the first `click tap` code to not run against the `.twodecplace` class? The code is currently incrementing the slider by 1,01 because both on change events are firing

Comment: show us your markup, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally `return false` or calling `stopPropagation()` on the event that's raised would solve this for you. However in this case you're using a delegated event handler, so you cannot do that as you rely on the event propagating for the event handler to run.

Instead you can check the `event.target` in the `.minus` handler and not execute the code if the target has the `.twodecplace` class. Try this:

```
$(document).on('click tap', '.fund-changer .minus', function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is('.twodecplace')) {
        var sliderCurrentValue = $(this).next().slider("option", "value");
        $(this).next().slider("value", sliderCurrentValue - 1);
    }
});

$(document).on('click tap', '.fund-changer .minus .twodecplace', function () {
    var sliderCurrentValue = $(this).next().slider("option", "value");
    $(this).next().slider("value", sliderCurrentValue - 0.01);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried adding `:not(.twodecplace)`? As so:

```
$(document).on('click tap', '.fund-changer .minus :not(.twodecplace)', function() {
    var sliderCurrentValue = $(this).next().slider("option", "value");
    $(this).next().slider("value", sliderCurrentValue - 1);
    return false;
});
```